# How to read the Values of argc and argv in main function (c) from file?

Tags: c, file, argv, argc

I want for main function in c program, read argc and argv from file.

How to read argv and argc from file in C language?

For example:

```
./prog --test=cpu --prime=1000 run
```

Change to:

```
./prog file.txt
```

File.txt is:

```
--test=cpu --prime=1000 run
```

Prog is a very big program.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the program, you can just do something like this:

```
./prog $(cat file.txt)
```

(assumung bash or similar shell).

Comment: This also works for Windows PowerShell, by the way. If you are looking for something that works that way on cmd.exe, though, you are out of luck. ;-)

Comment: I need to change the program. Because cat in ./prog $(cat file.txt) causes the same inputs to be placed next to ./prog and I have trouble executing this binary in another program. Because the flags or arguments of the other program interfere with this binary.

Comment: @ZahraHeydari: sorry, that doesn't make any sense. Please edit your question to explain the underlying problem.

Comment: @ZahraHeydari: You did not say anything about another program before...?